# After FB DNS issue of 10 Dec 2012, a single account fails on one computer but works on other computers

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

A friend of mine is having a problem accessing her Facebook account from her computer.  This problem started occurring the afternoon of 10 Dec 2012 when Facebook was having DNS issues that resulted in users being unable to access their account or were seeing only partial updates to their newsfeed etc.

My friend's problem continues to persist, but this happens only with HER account on HER home computer.  Her home page appears but with no newsfeed items, and her timeline page appears with only the header photo and profile photo but no timeline stories or pictures.

I have attempted to isolate the problem to either Facebook, or to her internet connection, or to her browser, or to her computer but with conflicting results as outlined below.

(1) HER fb account can be opened on OTHER computers successfully; her home page and timeline page appear normally.

(2) MY account will open on HER computer and MY pages appear normally, but HER pages do not open on HER computer.

(3) HER account will open on MY laptop over HER house internet wifi connection, and this works fine too.

(4) I tried to resolve the problem by installing several different browsers and also by clearing browser cache, temporary files, cookies, and history but this failed to resolve the problem with using HER account on HER computer.

What am I missing?  The problem seems isolated to only her account on only her computer.  Is there anything Facebook needs to see on her computer in the way of cookies, etc, that may have become corrupted, perhaps by the aforementioned Facebook DNS issue?  And how can this be resolved?

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)\

Answer (score 0):

Facebook and Frontier network are having DNS conflicts.  Mine has been in and out for 4 days now...sometimes down for 8 hours, then up for 10 minutes, then down again.

read here:

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2413060,00.asp